# How can I draw the string over the item in CheckedBoxList control?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am trying to draw or change the string of the item in the `CheckedListBox` control. So I have created the custom control which is derived from `CheckedListBox`.

```
public class CheckedListBoxAdv : CheckedListBox
{
    public CheckedListBoxAdv()
        :base()
    { 
    }

    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
         base.OnDrawItem(e);
        //I want to change the text alone this place. But I cannot access the text part of the item.

    }        
}
```

Is there any way to change the text alone?

Comment: Are you sure you need to draw on CheckedListBox? Why not simply change the item text?

Comment: Because i need to change the text based on the certain condition. Is there any way?

Comment: You don't need drawing. Simply change the item text.

Comment: I can understand your answer. But my need is to change the text alone in item drawing. Because it should change the text from collection of string. But value of the item will be original. For ex: If i populate item as "1". But i need to draw the "One" instead of that. But value will be "1". Hope you can understand

Comment: Yes and the solution is using a class as item and override ToString method of it.

Comment: Can you provide code snippet? It would be easy?

Comment: Yes, and it would be easy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any drawing. You can create a class `Item` containing a `Value` and a `Name` property and then override `ToString()` method of class to return what you need to show in `CheckedListBox`:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}
```

This way you can fill `CheckedListBox` with items. It shows `Name` properties but you also have access to `Value` property:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();

    this.checkedListBox1.Items.Add(new Item() { Value = 1, Name = "One" });
    this.checkedListBox1.Items.Add(new Item() { Value = 2, Name = "two" });
    this.checkedListBox1.Items.Add(new Item() { Value = 3, Name = "three" });

    //Change the Name of item at index 1 (2,"two")
    ((Item)this.checkedListBox1.Items[1]).Name = "Some Text";

    //But the value is untouched
    MessageBox.Show(((Item)this.checkedListBox1.Items[1]).Value.ToString());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `this.checkedListBoxName.Items` : checkedListBoxName is name of your checkedListBox

Ex:  `this.checkedListBoxName.Items[0] = "abc";`